# Using possessive apostrophes

Tags: attributive-nouns

How do you write "the nest of the (plural) goose" with correct apostrophes?

I am not sure if we say *geese* or *geese's*.

What would be the sentence structure?

Comment: You don't use the possessive form of the word if you use "of".

Comment: Hello, John. Our sister site, ELL, is intended for more basic questions. But as is the case with with ELU, some sign of reasonable research is expected.

Comment: ... the geese's nest ... is what I think you are looking for. But note that it would be quite correct to use 'goose' as either an adjective or a compounded noun (depending on your point of view) and say ... the goose nest ... (despite it being plural).

Comment: It's just a goose nest, unless your talking about specific geese and those geese's nests. Nobody "ever" says the nest of the geese.

Answer (score 1):

The nest of the **goose**.

No apostrophe.

The nest of the **geese**.

No apostrophe!

Comment: I think that the poster is asking whether to say "the nest of the geese" or "the nest of the geese's." If you think that's a possibility, too, I recommend that you address it as part of your answer.

Comment: Good point. I've completely re-written my answer!

Comment: I actually think he’s asking whether we say “The geese’ nest” or “The geese’s nest”

Comment: The question seems a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Of the goose = goose's

Of the geese = geese's

We need not use 'of' and apostrophe with the same noun(s).

Comment: I know; I should have spell-checked it.